# Parameterised makefile function

Tags: makefile

I'm using a makefile to run docker, where I first collect some modules to download, so that they can be cached and then run docker. I wanted to parameterize this, but I don't think I'm doing this in the best way. Pointers to make this more concise would be really appreciated.

```
franz:
    $(eval REPO_VERSION := $(shell grep franz requirements/github.txt | cut -d'@' -f3 | cut -d'#' -f1))
    if [ -d docker/franz ]; then \
        echo "Updating franz to [$(REPO_VERSION)]"; \
        cd docker/franz && git fetch && git checkout $(REPO_VERSION); \
    else \
        echo "Cloning franz to [$(REPO_VERSION)]"; \
        git clone --branch $(REPO_VERSION) git@github.com:dubizzle/franz.git docker/franz 2> /dev/null; \
    fi \

lilith:
    $(eval REPO_VERSION := $(shell grep lilith requirements/github.txt | cut -d'@' -f3 | cut -d'#' -f1))
    if [ -d docker/lilith ]; then \
        echo "Updating lilith to [$(REPO_VERSION)]"; \
        cd docker/lilith && git fetch && git checkout $(REPO_VERSION); \
    else \
        echo "Cloning lilith to [$(REPO_VERSION)]"; \
        git clone --branch $(REPO_VERSION) git@github.com:dubizzle/lilith.git docker/lilith 2> /dev/null; \
    fi \

dependencies: franz lilith
    git archive --format tar.gz --output docker/archive.tar.gz $(GIT_REF)
```

Basically, this first updates requirements that are on github, downloads them, checks what version is needed, and then updates to that version. If this could be made a function, a parameterised version would be:

```
$(eval REPO_VERSION := $(shell grep <repo-name> requirements/github.txt | cut -d'@' -f3 | cut -d'#' -f1))
if [ -d docker/<repo-name> ]; then \
    echo "Updating <repo-name> to [$(REPO_VERSION)]"; \
    cd docker/<repo-name> && git fetch && git checkout $(REPO_VERSION); \
else \
    echo "Cloning <repo-name> to [$(REPO_VERSION)]"; \
    git clone --branch $(REPO_VERSION) git@github.com:dubizzle/<repo-name>.git docker/<repo-name> 2> /dev/null; \
fi \
```

I've seen some examples using `define`, and `call`, and `eval`, but, I can't figure out the right combination to make it work.
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've once started writing a [Makefile tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Solar/Makefile) which makes use of `define`, `call` and `eval`. I never got around to finishing it, or explaining it in detail (because I switched to CMake), but the code that is there is fully functional.

Comment: @DevSolar will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial mentioned above, to pull the information to SO.

This is GNU make, mind.

Defining a template:

```
define RULES_template
$(1)/obj/%.o: $(1)/src/%.c
    $$(CC) $$(CFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS_global) $$(CFLAGS_$(1)) -c $$< -o $$@
endef
```

This uses one parameter (`$(1)`), which gets substituted as appropriate. The number of parameters is not declared, you just add `$(1)`, `$(2)` etc. to the template. Note the duplication of `$$` everywhere else.

```
$(foreach module,$(MODULES),$(eval $(call RULES_template,$(module))))
```

This calls the template mentioned above for each token in `$(MODULES)`.

`call RULES_template,foo` instantiates the template with one parameter, `foo`. `eval` then parses the output as Makefile syntax (as opposed to, for example, putting it into some variable).

This has been *ages* ago, and I never used that code in a productive environment, so I am a bit fuzzy on the details. I hope it helps, anyway.

---

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org) not only is cross-platform, but also has much better primitives to handle sophisticated build mechanics. I can recommend it.